# Operating on Pandas groups

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to perform multiple operations on a large dataframe (~3 million rows).
Using a small test-set representative of my data, I've come up with a solution. 
However the script runs extremely slowly when using the large dataset as input.

Here is the main loop of the application:

```
def run():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CARD_NO','CUSTOMER_ID','MODIFIED_DATE','STATUS','LOYALTY_CARD_ENROLLED'])

    foo = input.groupby('CARD_NO', as_index=False, sort=False)

    for name, group in foo:
        if len(group) == 1:
            df = df.append(group)
        else:
            dates = group['MODIFIED_DATE'].values
            if all_same(dates):
                df = df.append(group[group.STATUS == '1'])
            else:
                df = df.append(group[group.MODIFIED_DATE == most_recent(dates)])

    path = ''
    df.to_csv(path, sep=',', index=False)
```

The logic is as follows:
For each CARD_NO
- if there is only 1 CARD_NO, add row to new dataframe
- if there are > 1 of the same CARD_NO, check MODIFIED_DATE,
- if MODIFIED_DATEs are different, take the row with most recent date
- if all MODIFIED_DATES are equal, take whichever row has STATUS = 1

The slow-down occurs at each iteration around,

```
input.groupby('CARD_NO', as_index=False, sort=False)
```

I am currently trying to parallelize the loop by splitting the groups returned by the above statement, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach...

Am I overlooking a core functionality of Pandas?
Is there a better, more Pandas-esque way of solving this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Where are you reading your data from? Is it a csv file?

Comment: Yes. It is about 145mb in size.

Comment: constantly appending is not efficient at all; append the generated frame for each group to a list; concat at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a significant improvement in running time. The return statements appear to change the dataframe in place, significantly improving running time (~30 minutes for 3 million rows) and avoiding the need for secondary data structures.

```
def foo(df_of_grouped_data):
    group_length = len(df_of_grouped_data)

    if group_length == 1:
        return df_of_grouped_data
    else:
        dates = df_of_grouped_data['MODIFIED_DATE'].values
        if all_same(dates):
            return df_of_grouped_data[df_of_grouped_data.STATUS == '1']
        else:
            return df_of_grouped_data[df_of_grouped_data.MODIFIED_DATE == most_recent(dates)]

result = card_groups.apply(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two general tips:

1. For looping over a groupby object, you can try `apply`. For example,

   ```
   grouped = input.groupby('CARD_NO', as_index=False, sort=False))
   grouped.apply(example_function)
   ```

   Here, `example_function` is called for each group in your groupby object. You could write `example_function` to append to a data structure yourself, or if it has a return value, pandas will try to concatenate the return values into one dataframe.
2. Appending rows to dataframes is slow. You might be better off building some other data structure with each iteration of the loop, and then building your dataframe at the end. For example, you could make a list of dicts.

   ```
   data = []
   grouped = input.groupby('CARD_NO', as_index=False, sort=False)


   def example_function(row,data_list):
       row_dict = {}
       row_dict['length'] = len(row)
       row_dict['has_property_x'] = pandas.notnull(row['property_x'])
       data_list.append(row_dict)

   grouped.apply(example_function, data_list=data)
   pandas.DataFrame(data)
   ```